# Method not passing result back to main program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, methods

Having some real trouble understanding where I've gone wrong here.  I've marked in the code what and where.  I am using an XAML interface and do have objects for everything here.  The code compiles but the TextBlock will not update with the result from updateVTCShortCode Thanks for the help!

MAIN PROGRAM

```
namespace VTCPT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


        }

public void shortFormCodec_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //UPDATE THE SHORTCODE TEXTBLOCK
            updateVTCShortCode display = new updateVTCShortCode();
            display.mergeShortCode(longFormCodec.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(display.finalResult()))
            { shortFormCodec.Text = ".."; }
            else { shortFormCodec.Text = display.finalResult();
                shortFormCodec.Text = "test";
            }  /////THIS IS NOT ACTUALLY GETTING A RETURN 
        }

        public void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void updateShortForm(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void TextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void fsSiteBuild_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void updateSiteBuild(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = fsRoomDesig.Text.IndexOf(".");

            if (index > 0)
            { fsSiteBuild.Text = fsRoomDesig.Text.Substring(0, index); }
            else { fsSiteBuild.Text = ".."; }
        }

        private void vtcSystemName_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

updateVTCShortCode CLASS

```
namespace VTCPT
{
    class updateVTCShortCode
    {
        String result = "";
        public void mergeShortCode(String longFormCodec)
    {      if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco SX80"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SX80";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;

            }
            if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco Webex Codec Plus"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
            if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco Webex Codec Pro"))
            {
                String sendShortForm = "SRK";
                result = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
            }
 }
        public String finalResult()
                 { return result; } //////SHOULD BE GETTING SENT BACK TO MAIN PROGRAM
    }
}
```

Comment: Break point, step through the code, check variables on the way, do not *pass-go*. Then you should have all the ammunition you need to describe where things are going wrong.

Comment: @TheGeneral Breakpoints are showing me any issues and I've followed the variables...  Do you have a hint? LOL. I'm good with those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that in the following code taken from your `shortFormCodec_SelectionChanged` method. You set `shortFormCodec.Text = display.finalResult();` immediately followed by `shortFormCodec.Text = "test";`. The final result will never be visible because it is being immediately overwritten with "test".

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(display.finalResult()))
{
    shortFormCodec.Text = "..";
}
else
{
    shortFormCodec.Text = display.finalResult();
    shortFormCodec.Text = "test";
}
```

As TheGeneral suggested in the comments, you should be able to identify this using breakpoints and stepping through the code (using the F8 key) while watching the values of your variables and text fields. If you hover your mouse over the variables and the `.Text` section of any `shortFormCodec.Text` line it will show you its value at that point in the program.

However, I think you may find it helpful if you adjust your code to use an `if {} else if {} else {}` structure. I would also change the `finalResult()` method to a property as it's doing nothing but return a string. For example:

```
class updateVTCShortCode
{
    // You could set the default value to an empty string I.e. = ""
    // but having it set to "Not set" may help you spot any problems for now.
    // As long as you remember to call mergeShortCode() first, you would never
    // see "Not set" returned anyway. But this would help you spot that mistake.
    public string FinalResult { get; set; } = "Not set";

    public void mergeShortCode(String longFormCodec)
    {
        if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco SX80"))
        {
            String sendShortForm = "SX80";
            FinalResult = "V-T" + sendShortForm;

        } 
        else if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco Webex Codec Plus"))
        {
            String sendShortForm = "SRK";
            FinalResult = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
        }
        else if (longFormCodec.Equals("Cisco Webex Codec Pro"))
        {
            String sendShortForm = "SRK";
            FinalResult = "V-T" + sendShortForm;
        } else
        {
            // If longFormCodec is not matched, set the result to ".."
            FinalResult = "..";
        }
    }
```

By setting the final result to ".." in the else block of the `mergeShortCode()` method and setting a default value for the FinalResult property (even if it is an empty string I.e.  ""). You are preventing FinalResult ever being `null` and providing all possible outcomes from the one function. This means you can simplify the `shortFormCodec_SelectionChanged()` method to the following and easily reuse the `mergeShortCode()` method elsewhere:

```
    public void shortFormCodec_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //UPDATE THE SHORTCODE TEXTBLOCK
        updateVTCShortCode display = new updateVTCShortCode();
        display.mergeShortCode(longFormCodec.SelectedItem.ToString());
        shortFormCodec.Text = display.FinalResult;
    }

}
```